# Draw lines with CSS over an image - responsive behaviour

Tags: css, image, lines

I want to draw lines on an image by using CSS3, preferably to HTML5 Canvas.
I have found this tutorial and this demo which uses an html div:

http://www.monkeyandcrow.com/samples/css_lines/

However, when I try to do the effect on an image, the line is positioned outside of the image.

How can I get the line to be drawn directly on top of the image?

Also I would need the line width to be responsive, i.e., if I re-scale the browser window, the image is re-scaled (this I have been able by using Javascript, resizing the image dinamically), and I would need the pixel width of the image to re-scale as well.

Should I give up and use Canvas HTML5 instead? What about browser compatibility?

The complete code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Lines with CSS</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js"></script>
    <style>
        div.line{
            -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
               -moz-transform-origin: 0 50%;
                    transform-origin: 0 50%;

            height: 5px; /* Line width of 3 */
            background: #948C79; /* Black fill */
            opacity: 0.5;
            box-shadow: 0 0 8px #B99B7E;

            /* For some nice animation on the rotates: */
            -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
               -moz-transition:    -moz-transform 1s;
                    transition:         transform 1s;
          }

          div.line:hover{
            background: #C30;
            box-shadow: 0 0 8px #C30;
            opacity: 1;
          }

          div.line.active{
            background: #666;
            box-shadow: 0 0 8px #666;
            opacity: 1;
          }
    </style>
    <script>
        function createLine(x1,y1, x2,y2){
            var length = Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2));
            var angle  = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180 / Math.PI;
            var transform = 'rotate('+angle+'deg)';
            var line = $('<div>')
            .appendTo('#page')
            .addClass('line')
            .css({
              'position': 'relative',
              'transform': transform
                })
                .width(length)
                .offset({left: x1, top: y1});

            return line;
            } // function           

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Lines with CSS</p>

    <input type="button" value="Draw line" onClick="createLine(0,0,20,20);" />
    <div id="page" style="height:auto;"><p><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/86/Man_o%27war_cove_near_lulworth_dorset_arp.jpg/300px-Man_o%27war_cove_near_lulworth_dorset_arp.jpg" class="fotografia" /></p></div>
</body>
```

The **jsfiddle** is: https://jsfiddle.net/30xh1xpm/  ( notice that it doesn't even draw the line ).

Comment: __Did__ you try? You said you did. How can we know? Make an example of your effort and post it here. (and in jsfiddle.net or codepen.io or the like)

Comment: I have included the source code, which is adapted from the demo. I have done a jsfiddle, but it doesn't even draw the line. In my browser, with the source code saved to an html file, it does draw the line, but outside (below) the image.

Comment: In the fiddle, you hadn't included jQuery, and you tried to call the function onload rather than from the button. I corrected it and now it works. https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/30xh1xpm/1/ And I say it works, but it draws the line in the top left corner, above the image.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, I hadn't used jsfiddle before. Now I have an almost working example, with a background image inside a div, and even responsive. When I finish it, will update the code in the fiddle. I had thought of doing it with PHP + GD and jQuery-Ajax reload, which would be more browser compatible. The other solution would be HTML5 + Canvas but it also faces its compatibility problems. I stick, however, to the CSS aproach as I find it more interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve all of the issues, even IE8 behaviour, with a JS library which corrected it.

However, the strange behaviour of Firefox, even in the webpage example at the beginning, oblied me to do it throught PHP + GD, which is compatible with 100% of modern browsers. It seems CSS3 is the worst nightmare of the century for a serious developer.